# Simultaneous rosserial_arduino publisher and subscriber at different rates?

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

Thank yuo for taking the time to read and answer my question. I am fairly new to both ROS and arduino so please pardon me if my question is simplistic. I am trying to make a ROS robot using an MCU for the low level hardware handling and I followed the rosserial_arduino tutorial to combine the publisher and subscriber into one node that can both publish and subscribe:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh; 

std_msgs::String str_msg; 
char hello[6] = "hello"; 

ros::Publisher chatter("chatter", &str_msg); 

void messageCb(const std_msgs::Empty& toggle_msg){ 
  digitalWrite(PC13, HIGH-digitalRead(PC13));
}

ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Empty> sub("toggle_led", &messageCb); 

void setup(){
  nh.initNode(); 
  nh.advertise(chatter); 
  nh.subscribe(sub); 
  pinMode(PC13, OUTPUT); 
  str_msg.data = hello; 
}

void loop(){
  chatter.publish(&str_msg); 
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1000);
}
```

With the delay(1000) function in loop(), both the subscribing and publishing occur at 1hz. Is there a way for the subscriber to subscribe at a higher rate, while keeping the publisher publishing at 1hz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381941/simultaneous-rosserial_arduino-publisher-and-subscriber-at-different-rates?/) by [Chandra_jaoming](https://answers.ros.org/users/77299/chandra_jaoming/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For exactly such situations blocking delays are unadvisable. Instead, using [millis](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/) will get you the delay effect without blocking `loop()`.

Try this (code is untested):

```
unsigned long timeFrom = 0;
const unsigned long timeInterval = 5000;

void loop()
{
    // stuff that should be occurring every `timeInterval` milli-seconds
    if (millis() - timeFrom >= timeInterval)
    {
        chatter.publish(&str_msg);
        timeFrom = millis();
    }

    // stuff that should be occurring at loop frequency
    nh.spinOnce();
}
```

---

Originally posted by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) with karma: 228 on 2021-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chandra_jaoming](https://answers.ros.org/users/77299/chandra_jaoming/) on 2021-07-12**:
Now I see...thanks!